# Override a base variable in an inherited class

Tags: python

I have a base class called cashier and an inherited class called Trainee. I am trying to override variable called serviceTime in trainee class. I came up with the following. However, when I execute this I get:

`TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

even though I am using `object` in my base class. Can someone explain me what's going on?

```
class Cashier(object):
    def __init__(self, cashierNumber):
        self.cashierNumber = cashierNumber
        self.serviceTime = 1

class Trainee(Cashier):
    def __init__(self, cashierNumber):
        super(Trainee, self).__init__()
        self.serviceTime = 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass the parameter to the constructor of the parent class:

```
class Trainee(Cashier):
    def __init__(self, cashierNumber):
        super(Trainee, self).__init__(cashierNumber)
        self.serviceTime = 2
```